# Read WCF service endpoint address by name from web.config

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

Here I am trying to read my service endpoint address by name from web.config

```
ClientSection clientSection = (ClientSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");
var el = clientSection.Endpoints("SecService"); // I don't want to use index here as more endpoints may get added and its order may change
string addr = el.Address.ToString();
```

Is there a way I can read end point address based on name?

Here is my `web.config` file

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <client>
     <endpoint address="https://....................../FirstService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="1ServiceBinding" contract="abc.firstContractName" behaviorConfiguration="FirstServiceBehavior" name="FirstService" />
     <endpoint address="https://....................../SecService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="2ServiceBinding" contract="abc.secContractName" behaviorConfiguration="SecServiceBehavior" name="SecService" />
     <endpoint address="https://....................../ThirdService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="3ServiceBinding" contract="abc.3rdContractName" behaviorConfiguration="ThirdServiceBehavior" name="ThirdService" />
            </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

This will work `clientSection.Endpoints[0];`, but I am looking for a way to retrieve by name.

I.e. something like `clientSection.Endpoints["SecService"]`, but it's not working.

Comment: And your question is....?  Are you getting errors? No results?

Comment: Do you get it only using ConfigurationManager ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess you have to actually iterate through the endpoints:

```
string address;
for (int i = 0; i < clientSection.Endpoints.Count; i++)
{
    if (clientSection.Endpoints[i].Name == "SecService")
        address = clientSection.Endpoints[i].Address.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Good solution. I just used it. Thanks

Answer (score 24):

This is how I did it using Linq and C# 6.

First get the client section:

```
var client = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;
```

Then get the endpoint that's equal to endpointName:

```
var qasEndpoint = client.Endpoints.Cast<ChannelEndpointElement>()
    .SingleOrDefault(endpoint => endpoint.Name == endpointName);
```

Then get the url from the endpoint:

```
var endpointUrl = qasEndpoint?.Address.AbsoluteUri;
```

You can also get the endpoint name from the endpoint interface by using:

```
var endpointName = typeof (EndpointInterface).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks man, less code !!!, to get `EndPoint` by name(not index key) your second snipped code is a good solution.

Comment: casting using `as` instead prevents exceptions. nice.

Comment: that's great but I had to use.ToList() before it would let me use SingleOrDefault
client.Endpoints.Cast<ChannelEndpointElement>().ToList(), in case that is anyone elses issue

Answer (score 5):

Well, each client-side endpoint has a **name** - just instantiate your client proxy using **that name**:

```
ThirdServiceClient client = new ThirdServiceClient("ThirdService");
```

Doing this will read the right information from the config file automatically.

Comment: Maybe Op does not have a client proxy?

Comment: If you don't want to use ThirdServiceClient class ? Only using ConfigurationManager ?

Comment: Oh, that's from a Microsoft example that created the proxy class using the `svcutil.exe` program against a web service. I wondered what part of the .Net library ThirdServiceClient was in - but it was from a sample program. Gee, @marc_s, I think that's one of the most incomprehensible answers I've ever seen from you. Bad day, huh.