# How to Get WCF endpoint address url in C#

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there a way I can read end point address based on service client name?

Here is My ServiceReference Name:

```
TestServiceReference.TestServiceClient TestClient = new TestServiceReference.TestServiceClient ();
```

Here is my web.config file

```
 <endpoint address="http://....................../TestService.svc"
 behaviorConfiguration="webEndpoint" binding="webHttpBinding"
 bindingConfiguration="webHTTPBinding_abc" contract="TestServiceReference.ITestService" />**
```

Like Below URL

**var url = "http://............./TestService.svc";**

Comment: Have you tried - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572890/read-wcf-service-endpoint-address-by-name-from-web-config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try with :

```
TestClient.InnerChannel.RemoteAddress
```

Regards

Comment: So mak it as answered please

Answer (score 0):

TestClient.InnerChannel.RemoteAddress

Comment: Why do rewrite the same answer ?

Comment: i can't tick mark the answer because i have only 6 reputation point. so that i repeated Your answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay it was pretty easy to do, I just needed to use the **MetadataExchangeClient** to get the config. In the code all I had to do to get the MetaData Xml was this:

```
var meta = new System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient(new Uri("net.tcp://10.0.2.124:9000/TeraService/SetInstruments/mex"), System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClientMode.MetadataExchange);
var data = meta.GetMetadata();
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("xmlfile.xml");
x.Serialize(writer, data);
writer.Close();
```

Now I just need to spend some time getting the endpoints from that config.

Answer (score 0):

TestClient.Endpoint.Address.Uri is what worked for me.